# Error al ejecutar app después de instalar plugin

Tags: npm, select2, angular5

Quiero utilizar un plugin para realizar una búsqueda en un `select`. Encontré ng2-select2 en npm, lo instalé dentro de mi proyecto con: `npm i --save ng2-select2` y lo importe en mi app module.

Mi componente lo tengo hecho como se muestra en la [demo de la documentación del plugin](https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2-demo/tree/master/src/app/demos/basic) pero al correr la aplicación me muestra el siguiente mensaje:

> Please add Select2 library (js file) to the project. You can download it from https://github.com/select2/select2/tree/master/dist/js.

¿Por qué me sale ese error y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Hola Alejo, esta respuesta había sido reportada como de baja calidad. La he editado para que se ajuste algo mejor al formato del sitio pero, para próximas publicaciones, te recomiendo lee [ask] y seguir los consejos que encontrarás allí.

Comment: GRACIAS! LO TOMARÉ EN CUENTA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que intentas usar no es más que un *wrapper* de [select2](https://select2.org/) para Angular, por tanto, lo que te está diciendo es que necesitas añadir select2 como dependencia para que funcione. Puedes encontrar más información [aquí](https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2)

> For this plugin to work you need to add two javascript libraries to
> your project
>
> - Jquery
> - Select2
>
> First option and preferred one is to add libraries to your package
> builder.
>
> You can find example of how to add libraries to the Angular CLI in
> demo repository. You can also add it to webpack directly.
>
> Second option is to include libraries into your html head

Traducción:

Para hacer funcionar este plugin, necesitas añadir dos librerías javascript a tu proyecto:

- Jquery
- Select2

La primera y recomendada opción es añadir las librerías a tu *package builder* (*constructor de paquetes*, literalmente, seguramente tengas que añadir las librerías a `.angular-cli.json`).
Puedes encontrar un ejemplo de cómo añadir las librerías al Angular CLI en el repositorio de demostración.También puedes añadirlas a Webpack, directamente.

La segunda opción es añadirlas directamente a tu fichero inicial HTML,